# Check if inputs have text and enable button

Tags: javascript, forms, button, input

I'm trying to find a way that I can require two inputs to have text inside of them so I can toggle the `disabled` attribute on and off a button.

This would mean that when one input has text, the button is disabled. When both inputs have text, the button is enabled.

Here is my current code that I'm working with:

**HTML:**

```
<input name="e" placeholder="email">
<input name="p" placeholder="password">
<button id="submit_button" disabled>Submit</button>
```

**JavaScript (no jQuery):**

```
// Check if there is content in our form inputs and remove `disabled`
// from the button element.
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="e"], input[name="p"]');
var button = document.querySelector('#submit_button');

[].forEach.call(inputs, function (e) {
    e.addEventListener('input', function () {

        // Set states for email and password inputs
        if (this.value != "") {
            button.removeAttribute('disabled');
        } else {
            button.setAttribute('disabled', '');
        }
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aecaaa9e/7/)**

My thoughts with this code is that I would query the page for the two inputs, query for the button, and add an event listener that would check the input of each field, and when the value isn't empty, it would enable the button. Right now though, when you type something into either of the fields, regardless if both are filled in or not, the button becomes enabled.

How could I change this JavaScript so that both inputs must have text in order to enable the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? :

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="e"], input[name="p"]');
var button = document.querySelector('#submit_button');
[].forEach.call(inputs, function (e) {
    e.addEventListener('input', function () {
        var disabled = false;
        [].forEach.call(inputs, function (inputElem) {
            if(inputElem.value==''){
                disabled = true;
            }
        });
        // Set states for email and password inputs
        if (disabled) {
             button.setAttribute('disabled', '');
        } else {
            button.removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aecaaa9e/14/